# Git, pushing to remote

Tags: git

Lets suppose i am in a local ABC with branches `branch_A` and `branch_B`.

From `repo_A`, what are the differences between:

```
 - git push origin
 - git push origin branch_A
 - git push origin branch_A:branch_A
```

The reason for question is the following sequence of events, i find to be surprising:

```
11:05:56 ~/blah $ git push origin
Counting objects: 31, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (17/17), 1.28 KiB, done.
Total 17 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://git@mygit/myrepo.git
   141fc0d..d42c3b6  branch_B -> branch_B    // While i was in branch_A

11:06:02 ~/blah $ git branch
  branch_A
* branch_B
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing here that you are referring to your repositories as `repo_A` and `repo_B` when it appears that those are branch names within those repositories.

Comment: @MarkLongair, you're absolutely right. updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of behaviour of `git push origin` (if you haven't customized the config option `push.default`) is to push all "matching" branches.  That means that each local branch is pushed to one with the same name in origin *so long as a branch with that name already exists in origin*.  In this case, it seems that you have a `branch_B` branch in `origin` as well as locally.

The two other variants you quoted:

```
git push origin branch_A
git push origin branch_A:branch_A
```

.... are actually equivalent - if you don't include the `:` in the refspec to separate the source name from the destination name, it assumes that you mean the same name in the source and destination.